# Checking connectedness of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I am trying to use the Combinatorica package in a Mathematica version 8 in the following code:

```
gp = Graph[{1-> 3, 1 -> 2, 3 ->1}]
<< Combinatorica`
ConnectedQ[gp]
```

But this gives me an error message:

General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.

I have checked the guide but, the recommendation given could not solve this problem.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Do not load Combinatorica, it's mostly obsolete for graphs and if you're not careful, it'll conflict with built-in functionality in v8.  Just use `ConnectedGraphQ[gp]`.

Comment: @John: Welcome to the site! Please consider registering your account!

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to do it if you *really* need to use the *Combinatorica* package:

```
<< Combinatorica`
gpc = Combinatorica`FromOrderedPairs[{{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}}];
Combinatorica`StronglyConnectedComponents[gpc]
(* {{1, 3}, {2}}*)
```

Comment: BTW, don't even try to learn how to use Combinatorica from the docs. Better get a book like this one http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Discrete-Mathematics-Combinatorics-Mathematica/dp/0521121469

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorica is mostly obsoleted by version 8's built-in `Graph` data structure and the related functions.  Do not load Combinatorica in v8 or later, unless you need functionality that is not available built-in and you know how to work around the name conflicts between Combinatorica and built-in functions.

In this case just use

```
ConnectedGraphQ[gp]
```